# Is there a way to run a Django app without mod_wsgi or mod_passenger?

Tags: python, django, server, cgi, fastcgi

I've been trying to set up a Django Application on a shared hosting and I'm not allowed to use mod_wsgi neither mod_passenger. I've searched the web and found something about FastCG, but I'm not sure about it.
The issue is, I'm using a shared hosting and the support guy told me this:

> The mod_wsgi needs to modify Apache so that it can create its own mini server to handle .py files, but for obvious reasons we just are not able to do that for a shared server.
>
> If this is something you really need I would suggest looking at a VPS where you are able to make any modifications you desire.

I'd like to know if there are any known alternatives for this situation, where one needs to run a Djando App on a shared hosting service and it's not allowed to use neither mod_wsgi nor mod_passenger.

Comment: Would really recommend you just find another hosting service. You might try ``mod_wsgi-express`` and setup the Apache they have to proxy to it, but they likely aren't even going to easily allow a backend process to be started and kept running. They likely will not even have Apache header files in place to allow you to build ``mod_wsgi-express``. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi